# Storing values in global array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can't seem to get values to store in a global array. Code example below:

```
strategy("Array Issue", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
var vars = array.new_int(5)
var TRACK = 0

init() =>
     if (barstate.isfirst)
         array.set(vars, TRACK, 0)

run() =>
    var track = array.get(vars, TRACK)
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(track))
    var newTrack = track+1
    array.set(vars, TRACK, newTrack)
    var storedTrack = array.get(vars, TRACK)
    label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(storedTrack))

init()
run()
```

The "track" label is always 0 and the "storedTrack" label is always 1. So the array.set is working but not carrying over to the next call of run()

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` variables will be initialzed only once even if you have it in a function.

So, what's happening here is on the first bar `track`, `newTrack` and `storedTrack` are being initialized. But those lines will not be called again on the next executions. Therefore, their values never get updated.

Simply remove the `var` keyword.

In that case, only the first element of your array will be updated. That is because `TRACK` is always `0`. So, `array.set(vars, TRACK, newTrack)` will always write to index 0.